# Show dropdown menu only when hovered on span in li

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I want to show dropdown menu only when `hovered` on one word on `li (.$user->user_login.)`.
Currently I have hover on whole `li`, but I dont want the hover on "hello". 
When I hover on Username I must get a dropdown menu. Not when I hover on "Hello"

This is my code:

```
<ul class="top_login">
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( site_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a style="color: #20dae6;"> <?php $user=wp_get_current_user(); echo "Hello  <span style='color:#464646'>".$user->user_login."</span>"; ?> </a> 
        <ul class="profile_tab">
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>register-profile/">Edit Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/manage-bookings/">Manage Subscriptions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my **css**:

```
ul.top_login li {float:right;text-align:right;width:auto;position:relative;margin:0 5px;}

ul.top_login li a {color:#20dae6;font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase;cursor:pointer;}

/*SUB MENU*/

ul.profile_tab {background:#00777F;left:0;position:absolute;text-align:left;width:200px;z-index:999;display:block;}

ul.profile_tab li {height:22px;line-height:20px;display:block;float:left;text-align:left;margin:0;}

ul.top_login ul {display:none;}

ul.top_login li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

This is the rendered **HTML** we get:

```
<ul class="top_login">
   <li>
      <a title="Logout" href="http://localhost/iseasserver/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fiseasserver&_wpnonce=2846506c7c">Logout</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a style="color: #20dae6;">
      Hello
      <span style="color:#464646">admin</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="profile_tab">
         <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/iseasserver/pie-register-profile/">Edit Profile</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/iseasserver/manage-bookings/">Manage Subscriptions</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How do i do that?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's already wrapped in a `<span>`, style that by using `.top_login li a span { ... }`

Comment: Can you please read the question again. I have edited it.

Comment: @Aasim can you provide the HTML result when you've logged in, and perhaps create it in fiddle if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Jquery, see the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.top_login li a span').hover(function(){
        $(".profile_tab").toggle();
        });
});
```

When you `hover` on the username it will display the `menu profile_tab`, when the cursor `moves out`, the `menu` will `hide`, this is done using `hover` and `toggle` functionality.

See sample fiddle here: **[SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ps2vL7f/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use like below.

```
 .top_login li a:hover span {color:blue;}
```

EDIT:

According to your new requirement you need to use jQuery only for getting good result. Wait, I can give answer with CSS only. But it is ugly. If you are OK then try like below.

In CSS, you need to change from

```
ul.top_login li:hover ul {display:block;}
```

to this

```
ul.top_login li span:hover ul {display:block;}
```

You need to change your HTML structure like below.

```
 <ul class="top_login">
   <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( site_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a> </li>
   <li><a style="color: #20dae6;"> <?php $user=wp_get_current_user(); echo "Hello  <span style='color:#464646'>".$user->user_login.?> 
      <ul class="profile_tab">
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>register-profile/">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/manage-bookings/">Manage Subscriptions</a></li>
      </ul>
     </span></a> 
   </li>
  </ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L35gs6yd/)

Comment: This does not answer the question